# MVC 5 Create Validation error but valid ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to create within MVC 5 and am getting a validation error even though the ModelState is coming back valid.

**Error message**

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

and when I look at the message, it shows....

> The name 'e' does not exist in the current context

When I look at the POST data, the model that was created has all required fields filled in. I did notice that the model `ID` was assigned `0`. I'm not sure if that is the error or if it is supposed to pass a zero for the ID.

What might the problem be?

WosController.cs

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "id,woNumber,woDescription,dueDate,qty,item_id,releaseDate,parentWO_id,wip_id")] Wo wo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Wos.Add(wo);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(wo);
    }
```

Wo.cs

```
public partial class Wo
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Wo()
    {
        this.WoParts = new HashSet<WoPart>();
        this.WoStatuses = new HashSet<WoStatus>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string woNumber { get; set; }
    public string woDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dueDate { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> item_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> releaseDate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> parentWO_id { get; set; }
    public int wip_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> part_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WoPart> WoParts { get; set; }
    public virtual Wo woParentWO { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WoStatus> WoStatuses { get; set; }
    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
    public virtual Wip Wip { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *getting a validation error*.. what is the error?

Comment: And what does your `Wo` class look like?

Comment: with that error message.. how is it even working? what is `e`? that should be a compile-time error, not a run-time error? To get a better description of the error, why don't you try a `try-catch block` and catch the exception.. then when you debug it will tell you exactly what happened.

Comment: I wonder if there's something else going on. If you make your own Wo (in-code) and try to save it does it work? I wonder if there's something off about your db model

Comment: The ID of `0` is because it is a new `Wo`. That tells Entity Framework to perform an `INSERT` instead of an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your call to `SaveChangesAsync` in a `try...catch` like so:

```
try
{
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    var errorMessages = e.EntityValidationErrors
        .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
    var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
    var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(e.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);
    throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, e.EntityValidationErrors);
}
```

That will show you the actual properties causing the validation issues. Then, update your question with the results, if you still need assistance.

Comment: ok it shows that the 'status' field is required. I didn't include that field since it will has a default value defined in the SQL server DB. Why is it looking for that field if there is a default in the DB?

Comment: @Beengie As of right now, your application doesn't know that there is a default value waiting for `status` in the database.. but you still need to include it in your bind.  so just add `status` at the end of your binding.. like so: `[Bind(Include = "id,woNumber,woDescription,dueDate,qty,item_id,releaseDate,parentWO_id,wip_id, status")] Wo wo)`

Answer (score 1):

Likely, your database is out of sync with your entities. The `status` property is not required on your entity, and by default properties of type `string` are nullable. That would explain why you're passing validation on post, but failing on actually saving the entity.

Generally, it's best not to rely on the database setting a default value in the first place. Instead, have the property itself have a default value, and then it will always be fine, regardless of what's going on at the database level:

```
private string _status;
public string status
{
    get { return _status ?? "Default Value"; }
    set { _status = value;
}
```

Short of that, if status is truly not required, then you should ensure that the `status` column on your table is nullable.